# why isn't if statement working correctly

Tags: java

I'm grabbing the current win7 username which is rsmith but my if statement below displays:
0000 rsmith
2222 rsmith

Why doesn't my if == line work as expected? The userName IS rsmith

```
        String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        System.out.println("0000 " + userName + "\n");
        if (userName == "rsmith"){
            System.out.println("1111 " + userName + "\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("2222 " + userName + "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not compare Strings with `==`. You should use the `equals()` method.

```
 if (userName.equals("rsmith"){
   ..
 }
```

See [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/1115554) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The `==` operator compares whether two object references reference the same object in memory (referential equality), not whether they are equal. The String class' implementation of `equals()` compares whether two `String` objects have the same characters (value equality).

Hence, it would be:

```
if (userName.equals("rsmith") {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`==` tests for reference equality.

`.equals()` tests for value equality.

Consequently, if you actually want to test whether two strings have the same value you should use `.equals()`.

`==` is for testing whether two strings are the same object.

```
        String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
        System.out.println("0000 " + userName + "\n");
        if (userName.equals("rsmith")){
            System.out.println("1111 " + userName + "\n");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("2222 " + userName + "\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

**==**

compares 2 objects to check if they refer the same place in the memory

**.equals()**

compares the values of the object.

In your case, you need to use .equals to compare